# Javascript: can object or array value be used as second part of argument name?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have no idea why I can't find an answer to this, I feel kinda ridiculous for even asking but it's killing me.

Can function.modifier params be specified via iteration?

```
let colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue];
```

Example function uses .modifier(argument) as styling param.  (real-world ex: react-toastify)

```
function alert.red() // red widget
function alert.blue() // blue widget
function alert.green() // green widget
```

but `colors.forEach(color => alert.{color}('arg')) // error` ??

.. I mean.. seriously?  Am I missing something?

Comment: `colors.forEach(color => alert[color]('arg'))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `red`, `blue` and `green` functions as mere properties of `alert`, you can just call them like so: `alert[color]('arg')`

```js
const testAlert = {
  blue: function(message) {
     console.log('blue ' + message);
  },
  red: function(message) {
     console.log('red ' + message);
  }
};

['blue', 'red'].forEach(function(color) {
   testAlert[color]('message');
});
```